# Springdoc OpenAPI Starter for Spring Boot results in whitelabel error page

Tags: kotlin, swagger-ui, springdoc, springdoc-openui

I have a Spring Boot (3.1.4) application with Kotlin (1.9.0) and Gradle (Kotlin) with a basic REST API. I am currently trying to add Springdoc OpenAPI to document the REST API, but only receive a whitelabel error page. Not even an error message in the spring servers log.

**What I did**

I followed the guide at https://springdoc.org/#kotlin-support and added the following line to my dependencies:
`implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.2.0")`

**What I expected**

I expected to find the Swagger UI at http://localhost:9876/swagger-ui.html as described in the documentation https://springdoc.org/#getting-started.

**What happended instead**

Instead I was served a "Whitelabel Error Page".